# jQuery select() method is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get data for all selected options in select tag and for that I used onclick() function which gives the data of only clicked options. But if user selects all options with CTRL*A then no data will be received. I have tried to use select() which is not working in this case.

```js
//jQuery onclick()
$('select[name=sensors]').on('click', function(){
    $('#demo').text($('select[name=sensors]').val());
});

//jQuery select()
$('select[name=sensors]').select(function(){
    $('#demo2').text($('select[name=sensors]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select type='list' name='sensors' multiple>
  <option value= "e11">e11</option>
  <option value= "e12">e12</option>
  <option value= "e13">e13</option>
  <option value= "e14">e14</option>
</select>
<!--jQuery onclick()-->
<div id="demo"></div>
<!--jQuery select()-->
<div id="demo2"></div>
```

Comment: The `select` event is triggered when the user selects (highlights) text in applicable control elements, not when an option is selected.

Comment: `select` scope is limited to `input` & `text-area` only..It wont work on div

Comment: Jayababu
https://api.jquery.com/select/
Here it is used on div

Comment: It is unfortunate that they used `select` for inputs other than a `select`... Which just leads to confusion :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bind on `click`, but on `change`. This way even the changes coming from other kinds of interaction will be taken into account:

```js
$('select[name=sensors]').on('change', function(){
    $('#demo').text($('select[name=sensors]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select type='list' name='sensors' multiple>
  <option value= "e11">e11</option>
  <option value= "e12">e12</option>
  <option value= "e13">e13</option>
  <option value= "e14">e14</option>
</select>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

As for your experimentation with `select`, here's what [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/select/) says:

> The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text
>   selection inside it. This event is limited to 
>   fields and  boxes.

It's simply not relevant here, as the user isn't selecting *text* but options.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm want to know why select() is not working

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
$('select[name=sensors]').change(function(){
    $('#demo2').text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: While also correct, there was no point removing `on` if that was already in use.